# I can not see whole html source code by pressing ctrl+U

Tags: c#, html, css, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am working on scrapping of website. so i make one desktop application for that.

I check website using inspect element then i can see whole data of website but when i try to check website data using page source(ctrl+U) then there is nothing.
means i can't find any website data in page source but can see in firebug(inspect element).

because of this when i am trying to get data using c# coding then i am getting only page source data which doesn't contains any website data only contains schema(structure) and js links.

see below image of firebug.

[image: Page source in Firebug]

And this is page source image.

[image: Page source]

Comment: Maybe they are appended to document dynamically.

Comment: Yes i also think so.but there is any other way to scrap data from this kind of website.?

Comment: What do you mean to "scrap data"? You are comparing dev tools with initial output which was send to browser. You can search for elements added dynamically in dev tools.

Comment: scrap data means copy data from website programmatic.

Comment: are you using web-forms ??

Comment: No i made one desktop application in which i load third party website and copy particular data from website to my database.

Answer (score 0):

You met the js-powered site. The content is dynamicly loaded thru js, thus it's not visible in page-source. Turn to the scrape libraries that support *js code evaluation*. See here [an example](http://scraping.pro/javascript-protected-content-scrape/).

Comment: Do you know any scrape libraries that support js code.?

Comment: @KaranPatel, what language do you use? See the post I mentioned and its comments (if using *python*).

Comment: I am using c# language.

Comment: @KaranPatel, have you googled over for "c# scrape library with javascript support"

Comment: @KaranPatel, Usually, such dynamic websites get their data from somewhere via JSON, all you need to do is find out from where the data is dynamically downloaded, (using devtools in browser), and then download it yourself in your app.